# Couchbase XDCR migration

Tags: couchbase

we are migrating the data from one couchbase cluster to another couchbase cluster using XDCR.
We can check in the admin console about the XDCR progress.
I want to do bucket level **data** verification among two data base cluster
I think there is no straight forward method to do data verification , is there any other workaround to achieve this ???

Comment: By data verification, you mean you want to check that the data is the same in both clusters?